# How to see Sqlite database of an app installed on Bluestack emulator?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, bluestacks

So I have installed this SQLite app on Bluestack emulator but when I go into the Android Device Monitor I don't see any process with the name of my project in the emulator.
When I click on Data folder in the file explorer nothing actually happens even though it has this ">" greater than sign means there is data inside this folder but when I click the sign goes away for a few seconds but comes back without any other change.

[image: Link here]

Comment: Your process doesn't need to be running to inspect the database

Comment: When I click on data folder inside file Explorer nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your database in /data/data/yourpackage/databases/yourdatabase.db
Copy it to your pc and inspect it with SQLiteStudio.
You can copy it with the adb pull command.

Comment: can you please write the command as I'm not too familiar with adb.

Comment: adb pull /data/data/yourpackage/databases/database.db C:\database.db

Comment: what should I do now.

Comment: I'd suggest using the GenyMotion emulator, you have access with that. Another option is to copy the database, within the App, to an accessible location.